# Random cryptic question (don't know reason for answer)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Got a random question from an online iq test that I don't understand. Can someone help me out? Here's the question: 
[image]

The answer is

> 888

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  For content that is not your own, please provide attribution. Using someone else's content without (at minimum) disclosing where it came from is plagiarism, and such posts are deleted.  Also, the [tag:no-computers] tag seems random and inapplicable - you should probably edit it to a better one.

Comment: The above equation, $X/3=X$, doesn't make much sense.  $X/3=x$ was probably intended.

Comment: here is the source : https://iqhaven.com/mytests1/lensatest_iqtest/lensatest_iqtest.htm

Comment: Well, it was nice of OP to adhere to the "No discussing with others or posting your solutions elsewhere" rule, wasn't it?  :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

For the triangle:

> Inside the Equilateral triangle there are two letters
>  E = 5 &  L = 12 so they both form the number 512
>  The Equilateral triangle has 3 equal sides
>   X represent each side so the question is asking us to find the answer to the equation X^3 = 512
>  And the answer is X = 8
>  So XXX  = 888

For the equation to the right:

> X is the 24th letter in the alphabet
>  So 24/3 = 8
>  Thanks @ffao for pointing that out.

Comment: for the right equation: X is the 24th letter of the alphabet

Comment: KMS you are welcome, @ffao Thanks a lot, I got confused because They would have changed the font of X,  but yeah you are right

Comment: That's porobably it, but it's too cryptic for its own good. The area of an equilateral triangle is √3 ∕ 4 x² ≈ 0.433 x². Shouldn't the _EL_ rather be inside a cube?

Comment: @MOehm Yeah, If we are talking about a better question then it would be better to put the EL inside a cube and change certain X's to lower case....